# Does TFS Record the Parameters to a Build?

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

When queueing a new build, we get the option to change the default parameters. Do these changes get recorded somewhere, either in the TFS Operational Store or in the TFS Data Warehouse?

Comment: Why in the world would anyone downvote this question, and then not say why? Is there something wrong with the question?

Answer (score 1):

These parameters should be available in the Team Foundation Build Operational Store, according to the behavior described in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms244687.aspx.

Answer (score 1):

My advice is to log them as part of the build workflow, then the log will be stored with the build outputs.  If you read the ALM Ranger Build Guidance they suggest taking this approach, and I believe the BRDLite customized Build Process Template that ships with the guidance does this:  http://rabcg.codeplex.com/