# Is the XML passed to TFS build event subscribers stored in TFS DB?

Tags: tfs, tfs-sdk

I have set up a custom build event handler for TFS 2012 builds via the SOAP web service option. This handlers works nicely and is built to work with the XML payload that TFS gives us.

I am now trying to build a web page that can show similar information for a build. However, I don't want to go through the trouble of trying to re-create my XML payload or modify my interfaces to deal with TFS objects instead of objects I defined from parsing the payload.

So, is this event XML stored somewhere in the DB? Is it accessible or easily generated via the TFS API?

Comment: Similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7542213/does-tfs-record-the-parameters-to-a-build

Answer (score 3):

Yes it is.  You can find it in the Event column of the tfs event queue.

Here is a sample export of the queue (XML truncated here):

```
PartitionId     262696
Id              1
Event           <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?><WorkItemChangedEvent xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><PortfolioProject>REDACTED</PortfolioProject><ProjectNodeId>8afd8744-c011-43b2-a25...(truncated)
EventType       WorkItemChangedEvent
Status          Processed
ClientHostName  NULL
CreatedTime     2013-08-11 18:13:59.767
```